# Looking for a simple OSS load balancer for JVM processes

Tags: java

[image]

I am looking for a component for the red box. I'd like an OSS load balancer that can consume from a JMS queue and trigger a new JVM process in different machines. Each job triggered is independent and its results are stored in a single backend DBMS.

I suppose each JVM must have some sort of communication with the load balancer. I was considering using something like very a lightweight daemon in each machine listening to the queue (basically moving the red box inside the blue boxes in the right), but then each one should be able to communicate to each other somehow.

I wonder if there's already some pattern or solution for this situation.